# What would cause a mouse offset between a local TinyCore installation and remote VNC console?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vnc, qemu

I have this odd issue with TinyCore Linux (v7.2.0) running inside of QEMU on Linux. When I start the VM and run my VNC client the local and remote pointer are out of sync. The offset is about 2 inch or so when I move my pointer around.

The actual VM is being invoked through GNS3 as this VM will be one of my hosts in GNS3. However GNS3 still uses a standard QEMU installation on the Linux host.

I have tried using the `-usbtablet` option in my QEMU config. It makes no difference to the pointer.

Here is a GIF of what the problem looks like:

[image: Tiny Core GIF]

Any idea what would cause Tiny Core to not sync up? Could be a driver / module issue since Tiny Core is a super small distro?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you still have this issue.

I got it mostly resolved with:

Installing libXmu (`tce-load -wi libXmu.tcz`)

Via GUI:

Control Panel > Mouse Tool > change: Mouse Speed = 1

(this looks to be remembered across reboots)

Via CLI:

```
xset mouse 1 0
```

(verify with `xset q`)

(doesn't get remembered across reboots by default)

At bootup:

in `/opt/bootlocal` add the following lines.

```
[ ! -e "$TCEDIR"/libXmu.tcz ] && sudo -u tc tce-load -wi libXmu.tcz
sudo -u tc echo "xset m 1/1 0" > /home/tc/.mouse_config
sudo chown tc:staff /home/tc/.mouse_config
sudo -u tc chmod +x og= /home/tc/.mouse_config
```

(this will take effect with the second boot of the VM)

Just resently a feature was added to prevent the mouse jumpt to a window when a new window is opened. This requires TCL 10.1 (or Core 10.0 with the latest `flwm_topside` extension installed)

in `~/.profile` add the following line:

```
export NOWARP=1
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to install xorg from the repo to get a mouse with absolute positioning.